# All possible unique sets in specific size

Tags: java, math, set

Are there any libraries out there to make these kind of set operations.

I have a set of (x,y) points. Then i need to create a Set (Family) of Sets. Each Set in the family should contain a certain number of elements. The order of the elements in a set doesn't matter. So [m, l, n] is the same set as [l, m, n].

Comment: AFAICS you need a `Point` class, then a class who holds a `Set<Point>`, let's say, `Figure` and another class that holds a `Set<Figure>`. No need of a third-party library to handle this.

Comment: Generating all the combinations first requires exponentially more memory.  However, if you process each combination as you generation you have small fixed memory usage.  Generating the combinations is a matter of a loop and recursion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're asking for are called [combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination). Guava has [a method](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html#permutations%28java.util.Collection%29) to compute permutations, which are related. If you only need combinations, though, the lesser-known [combinatoricslib](https://code.google.com/p/combinatoricslib/) looks like [The Right Thing](https://code.google.com/p/combinatoricslib/#3._Simple_combinations). Here's an example from that library's site, using `String`s:

```
// Create the initial vector
ICombinatoricsVector<String> initialVector = Factory.createVector(
   new String[] { "red", "black", "white", "green", "blue" } );

// Create a simple combination generator to generate 3-combinations of the initial vector
Generator<String> gen = Factory.createSimpleCombinationGenerator(initialVector, 3);

// Print all possible combinations
for (ICombinatoricsVector<String> combination : gen) {
   System.out.println(combination);
}
```

Comment: I don't think he's asking for combinations. He's just asking for a data structure that he can use to store his points.

Comment: As far as I understand, he needs to generate all possible subsets of some size `k`.

Comment: Based on this, I think he's asking to generate combinations of a fixed length, which is to say permutations where order doesn't matter: "Then i need to create a Set (Family) of Sets. Each Set in the family should contain a certain number of elements. The order of the elements in a set doesn't matter. So [m, l, n] is the same set as [l, m, n]."